# iPhone - downloading images to app directory

Tags: iphone, image, file, download

I could really use some help with files (images) download/save application process.

I need some methods to:

- Create hidden (accessable from my app only) directory
- Save files (images + maybe 1 XML file) to such directory
- List all of these directories and later list all files the selected directory contains

I know how to do it on Android, however on iPhone it seems a bit unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to obtain your application's Documents directory path. This directory is only accessible from your application.

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
return basePath;
}
```

To save and load files from there, you can use any of a wide range of methods, from C functions (`fopen` and the like) to Cocoa convenience methods like NSString's

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error
```